# Batch Create Graphic Sheets in R

Tags: r, batch-processing

I am very new to R and seem to be having a hard time creating a for loop to create a PDF graphic sheet containing 6 charts (2 columns x 3 rows).  I am using the following loop to import CSV's into seperate data frames.

```
##create filenames object that lists the csv files in a folder
filenames <-  list.files(path="C:/Survey_Stage/Data_Transfer/Survey_Stage/Stage_Discharge_Relations/CIDA/", pattern="*.csv")

##run loop that imports each csv file in the folder, creates a dataframe, assigns the filename to the dataframe, and adds column names
for(i in filenames)
{
filepath <-file.path("C:/Survey_Stage/Data_Transfer/Survey_Stage/Stage_Discharge_Relations/CIDA/",    paste(i, sep=","))
assign(i, read.table(filepath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")[,c('SP_elev', 'flow')])
}
```

At this point in my project i have a total of 23 csv's and want to produce 6 graphic sheets.

Heres an example of a data frame that is produced from in the csv import loop.

```
> Z041R.csv
    SP_elev  flow
1  840.5466  5430
2  840.9774  8285
3  841.1020  9162
4  841.2236 10175
5  842.4053 18450
6  840.7600  6780
7  840.9493  8110
8  841.6590 12700
9  842.6615 20200
10 841.2138 10175
11 845.0801 41977
12 841.4786 11431
13 841.6829 13000
14 845.1645 42500
15 841.6142 12400
16 841.2574 10200
17 842.2315 16400
18 840.9390  8040
```

I flow is the independent variable and SP_elev to be the dependent variable. I have figured out how to create the grahic sheets individually but would really like a for loop to automate the process.  Any ideas?

Heres the loop i have tried.

```
##run loop to plot the csv files 

pdf(file="myplots.pdf",paper="letter")

par(mfrow=c(3,2)) 

for(i in filenames)
{
plot (data.frame(i[flow], i[elevation]), xlab=expression(paste("Discharge (", ft^3, "/s)",sep = "")), ylab= "Elevation (m)", main = i)
}

dev.off()
```

Thanks,

Dubbdan

Comment: Doesnt that just make a blank plot with 3 rows and 2 columns.  i cant seem to get each data frame to plot.

Comment: So show us your code and we will try to debug it

Comment: I edited my original post

Comment: Put flow and SP_elev into quotes. Why it is `elevation` instead of `SP_elev` btw? I think it should be something like `plot (data.frame(i["flow"], i["SP_elev"]), xlab=expression(paste("Discharge (", ft^3, "/s)",sep = "")), ylab= "Elevation (m)", main = i)`

Comment: The SP_ prefix simply means State Plane.  I tired your modifications and i received the following error:

Error in rep(xat[1L:nx], rep(ny, nx)) : invalid 'times' argument

Comment: I didn't ask what SP means, I asked why if in your data.frames there are two columns called `flow` and `SP_elev`, you parse into your plot and unexsisting column called `elevation`? Re the error, where in the code you ran a `rep()` function? I don't see it.

Comment: I didnt use the rep() function.  Somehow the loop thinks we did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a minor tweak (with annotations) of [@BigFinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3494714/bigfinger)'s solution:

```
# read in list of filenames
filenames <- list.files(path="C:/Survey_Stage/Data_Transfer/Survey_Stage/Stage_Discharge_Relations/CIDA/", pattern="*.csv")

# open the PDF device
pdf(file="myplots.pdf", paper="letter")

# loop through the filenames
for(i in filenames) {

  # build the path to the current file
  filepath <- file.path("C:/Survey_Stage/Data_Transfer/Survey_Stage/Stage_Discharge_Relations/CIDA", paste(i))

  # read in the data frame
  dat <- read.csv(filepath)

  # plot the chart using column names just incase they aren't all in the same exact format
  plot (dat[,c('SP_elev', 'flow')], xlab=expression(paste("Discharge (", ft^3, "/s)",sep = "")), ylab= "Elevation (m)", main = i)

}

# close the PDF device
dev.off()
```

You can do a `main = gsub(".csv", "", i, fixed=TRUE)` in the `plot` call if you don't want the `.csv` in the plot title.

Comment: The above solution works well.  I had to add the line par(mfrow=c(3,2)) to make the array of plots. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: If i have a data frame name of 'Z001R.csv' and i want the main title to read 001R, how do i use gsub to remove the first character 'Z' and the file extension '.csv'?

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  Any chance you can explain the syntax of the general expression '(^Z|\\.csv$)' a little more?

Comment: Sure. The parens aren't rly needed but I do group-based substitutions alot, so you cld just do `"^Z|\\.csv$"`. The `|` is just *regex1* "or" *regex2*. `^Z` says *"`Z` at the start of the string"*. `\\.` escapes the period which is a special regex char. `\\.csv$` says *"`.csv` at the end of the string"*. Lots more help via `?regex` at the R console and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483787/looking-for-a-beginners-primer-tutorial-guide-on-regular-expressions

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this. Assuming each csv file has exactly 2 columns. Otherwise, extract the columns you need from variable "crtdata.

```
pdf(file="myplots.pdf",paper="letter")
for(i in filenames)
{
    crtdata = read.csv(i)
    plot (crtdata, xlab=expression(paste("Discharge (", ft^3, "/s)",sep = "")), ylab= "Elevation (m)", main = i)
}
dev.off()
```

Comment: I have been using the pdf() command.  I think my problem is refering to the list of data frame names.  I have tried simply using 'i' in the for loop.  I think there is some syntax i am missing.  I edited my original post to show what loop i am trying.